# excel Vba: if any error show msgBox dont open Microsoft visual basics for application

Tags: excel, vba

Hello as soon as I have an error message in my UserForm1, e.g. variable not defined, wrong syntax, debugging message etc. microsoft visual basics for application opens automatically. But I dont want that opens microsoft visual basics for application I want a normal msgBox to open with the following message:
"Error has occurred "error name here" contact admin"

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: **Syntax errors** and **Compiler Errors** like `Variable not defined` shouldn't occur when you always use `Option Explicit` and compile the code (Debug->Compile Project) after you wrote/modified the code. **Runtime Errors** can be handled by implementing error handlers, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement. I recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKIOIXriXEI

Comment: it doesn't realy explain what I want. Since my UI will be public for everyone, I will protect editing of the codes with password, so that no one can see the code (hopefully I can implement something like that when the time comes) but as soon as someone should get an error message when he e.g. clicks a button or opens a new userform by clicking, I want that the other options are still usable therefore only a message with error name should come and the message should be draggable.

Comment: So have a closer look onto the error handling (e.g. _on error goto ErrHandling_). In the video recommend to you, the basics are described.

Comment: I don't understand. What "other options"? Basically, when you have an error and the default message comes, you have the option to Debug (which is not possible for protected code), to press Help (which is usually completely useless) or to stop. If you catch an error via error handler, you can show for example a MsgBox, but after that it's up to you as programmer to decide what to do, and that is highly depending on the error you get and how you want/can handle it.